# How to parse date into the array?

Tags: javascript

> 11.06.2012 17:40

All what I need it's to put in array values

```
mydate.day = 11;
mydate.month = 6;
mydate.year = 2012;
mydate.hours = 17;
mydate.minutes = 40;
```

Comment: O.K. So why won't you do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
"11.06.2012 17:40".split(/[.: ]/).map(Number);
//[11, 6, 2012, 17, 40]
```

Comment: I Liked that! I didn't know you can split with a regex!

Comment: yeah, but how to get it, Number[0] returns undefind?

Comment: @AquaVita `var arr = "11.06.2012 17:40".split(/[.: ]/).map(Number);` `alert(arr[0]);`

Comment: ohh, sorry, mydate = "11.06.2012 17:40".split(/[.:]/).map(Number); canonical!

Comment: ha, you was first, thank you folk!

Comment: +1 excellent, i would never learn regex :(

Comment: @AquaVita in that case, you access mydate[0] mydate[1] etc.

Comment: Just note that this excellent answer works in IE9+

Comment: @gdoron I take it from that that it won't work in IE 8-? (I'm fairly sure they are missing `Array.map()` somewhere down there.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel you can use [es5shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim), and not worry about it